# Gradle Failure while installation (Windows 11)

Tags: gradle

HELP !! I just installed Gradle for the first time. After extracting the file and checking the Gradle Version in CMD, the result goes like this:

//
C:\Users\PC>gradle -version

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not initialize native services.
> Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 11 amd64.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> //

THANKS :)

HELP PLEASE................................

Comment: Not sure since you don't give a whole lot of details, but you could try this thread at the gradle forums:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/running-gradle-failed-to-load-native-platform-dll-error/18863